# D3.js change background opacity with transition

Tags: d3.js, background, opacity

Good evening, 
How can I change the background opacity smoothly (using transition in d3.js) in the div. If i change the opacity property, then disappears block content. If i use RGBA property, before animation background is reset to white and newly defined color.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Please show your code attempts. Stack Overflow is not a code for free service.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not written in a way that makes helping you easy but try:

```
d3.selectAll("#divname")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("opacity", "0")
  .attr("fill", "#WXYZ")
```